# Is it correct and natural to begin telling a story with "there was this one time when..."?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to begin telling a story with *there was this one time when...*? For example:

> **There was this one time** when I was walking down the street and met the president.

If it's not natural, how would you begin telling a story?

Comment: Seems fine to me.  There are about 5 million ways that you can start are story (and more ways are being discovered all the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to answer with that example and without context, but I'll try.

"**There was this one time when** X..." works best when "X" is an example of a more general and repeating thing or phenomenon that you've already been talking about. For example, if you've been talking about all the interesting people you've met in your life, you could then say the sentence that you've provided. Or if you've been talking about how much you like to go walking down the street (this scenario being somewhat artificial), it would also make sense to use "there was this one time when I was walking down the street and" something interesting happened.

The preceding discussion doesn't have to be long. It can literally just be: "I like to go for walks. There was this one time that I was on a walk and" whatever.

But if you're starting a story that's not at least minimally an example of something that's been introduced, my feeling is that you probably wouldn't use that expression. It's not terrible to use it; it just perhaps isn't the most natural way to start, in my opinion. Instead, you could start with "I was once." That's pretty common and there are no prerequisites for it.

I'd be interested in hearing other views, but my reaction is that when you say "there was this one time," it needs to have been set up to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. It's awkward. The whole phrase in bold could be replaced by the single word "once"

As written, it would say something to me about the  speaker - perhaps a teenager, not an educated adult.  So use it to start your story if that's an inference you want to suggest.

Comment: Plenty of educated adults use "there was this one time." It's common.